# Why is my code not working while converting bulk csv to json?

Tags: python, json, csv

There are two CSV files. I need to convert to JSON. Code is below

```
import csv 
import json 
import os
import glob

os.chdir(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\test' )
result = glob.glob( '*.csv' )
print (result) 
def make_json(csvFile, jsonFile): 
    csvFile, jsonFile = '',''
    for i in result:
        data = {} 
        with open(csvFile, encoding='utf-8') as csvf: 
            csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf) 
            for rows in csvReader: 
                key = rows['id'] 
                data[key] = rows 
        with open(jsonFile, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf: 
            jsonf.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4)) 
        csvFilePath =f"{i}"
        jsonFilePath =f"{i.split('.')[-2]}.json"
make_json(csvFile, jsonFile)
```

I got error > `csvFile is not mentioned`. But the third line from the end mentions the CSV file.

- Disclaimer. Please find the error in the code. I already know of the working code which is in pandas

Comment: ``csvFilePath`` passed as argument to ``make_json`` but where is it initialized ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the correct code, but I would recommend you learn to use the python debugger so you can resolve any logic flaws in your code next time.  Documentation on the python debugger can be found here:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html

Your code was structured in a way that meant for each csv file, you were not setting the file name until after you attempted to open it.  The immediate error you saw was caused because you tried to call make_json() before you defined the values for csvFile and jsonFile.

I would recommend changing the code to:

```
import csv
import json
import glob

def make_json(csvList):
    for csvFile in csvList:
        data = {}
        with open(csvFile, encoding='utf-8') as csvf:
            csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf)
            for rows in csvReader:
                key = rows['id']
                data[key] = rows
        jsonFile =f"{csvFile.split('.')[-2]}.json"
        with open(jsonFile, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf:
            jsonf.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

make_json(glob.glob('*.csv'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try this

```
import csv, json, os, glob

os.chdir(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\test' )
result = glob.glob( '*.csv' )
print(result)

def make_json(): 
    for i in result:
        with open(i, encoding='utf-8') as csvf: 
            data = [row for row in csv.DictReader(csvf)]
            
        with open(f"{i.split('.')[-2]}.json", 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf: 
            json.dump(data, jsonf)

make_json()
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not initialize both the arguments of make_json() - (csvFilePath & jsonFilePath)